# Android google dfp ads

Tags: java, android, ads, google-dfp

Was trying to implement native dfp ads for a week.

The dfp server has targeting and frequency cap limit. Targeting works fine, all problems are because of frequency cap.

[Dfp frequency cap option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTiQQ.jpg)

When I disable that checkbox it works like a charm. But when that checkbox is active, ads are not delivered on SOME devices with error code 3. Not all.

The code I'm using is completely from [google sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/java/doubleclick/CustomRenderingExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/gms/customrenderingexample/MainActivity.java). I use only native content ad.
I also have targeting:

> addCustomTargeting(key, value)

But it works fine.

The docs say it can be because no user identifier was provided or cap limit. Don't think it is a cap limit because I don't get ads at all. So maybe it is because dfp server can't identify user. But what can I do with this? Docs say that identifier is automatically sent.

I also found PPID. I tried to send it as in this [sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/java/advanced/APIDemo/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/apidemo/DFPPPIDFragment.java), but seems like it has 0 impact.

I wonder what can I do from my side? Also I have access to dfp console. I just don't know the reason.

IOS works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was not with my client. After some workarounds on dfp server (not sure what they did exactly) and resetting Google Advertising Id on Android device it worked